CSS mix-blend-mode for maximum contrast
After going through all the blend modes, there seems to be no solution for maximum contrast. Ideally, the text should be only black or white, so that contrast can be maximized with any background color. Not sure if this is possible with css. See this example: https://codepen.io/YhomasV/pen/vYqRGyN
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="a">
            <div class="a1"><p style="mix-blend-mode: normal">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a2"><p style="mix-blend-mode: normal">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a3"><p style="mix-blend-mode: normal">Hello</p></div>
            <p class="a4">normal</p>
        </div>
        <div class="a">
            <div class="a1"><p style="mix-blend-mode: screen">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a2"><p style="mix-blend-mode: screen">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a3"><p style="mix-blend-mode: screen">Hello</p></div>
            <p class="a4">screen</p>
        </div>
        <div class="a">
            <div class="a1"><p style="mix-blend-mode: overlay">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a2"><p style="mix-blend-mode: overlay">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a3"><p style="mix-blend-mode: overlay">Hello</p></div>
            <p class="a4">overlay</p>
        </div>
        <div class="a">
            <div class="a1"><p style="mix-blend-mode: darken">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a2"><p style="mix-blend-mode: darken">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a3"><p style="mix-blend-mode: darken">Hello</p></div>
            <p class="a4">darken</p>
        </div>
        <div class="a">
            <div class="a1"><p style="mix-blend-mode: lighten">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a2"><p style="mix-blend-mode: lighten">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a3"><p style="mix-blend-mode: lighten">Hello</p></div>
            <p class="a4">lighten</p>
        </div>
        <div class="a">
            <div class="a1"><p style="mix-blend-mode: multiply">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a2"><p style="mix-blend-mode: multiply">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a3"><p style="mix-blend-mode: multiply">Hello</p></div>
            <p class="a4">multiply</p>
        </div>
        <div class="a">
            <div class="a1"><p style="mix-blend-mode: hue">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a2"><p style="mix-blend-mode: hue">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a3"><p style="mix-blend-mode: hue">Hello</p></div>
            <p class="a4">hue</p>
        </div>
        <div class="a">
            <div class="a1"><p style="mix-blend-mode: saturation">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a2"><p style="mix-blend-mode: saturation">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a3"><p style="mix-blend-mode: saturation">Hello</p></div>
            <p class="a4">saturation</p>
        </div>
        <div class="a">
            <div class="a1"><p style="mix-blend-mode: color">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a2"><p style="mix-blend-mode: color">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a3"><p style="mix-blend-mode: color">Hello</p></div>
            <p class="a4">color</p>
        </div>
        <div class="a">
            <div class="a1"><p style="mix-blend-mode: luminosity">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a2"><p style="mix-blend-mode: luminosity">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a3"><p style="mix-blend-mode: luminosity">Hello</p></div>
            <p class="a4">luminosity</p>
        </div>
        <div class="a">
            <div class="a1"><p style="mix-blend-mode: exclusion">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a2"><p style="mix-blend-mode: exclusion">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a3"><p style="mix-blend-mode: exclusion">Hello</p></div>
            <p class="a4">exclusion</p>
        </div>
        <div class="a">
            <div class="a1"><p style="mix-blend-mode: color-dodge">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a2"><p style="mix-blend-mode: color-dodge">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a3"><p style="mix-blend-mode: color-dodge">Hello</p></div>
            <p class="a4">color-dodge</p>
        </div>
        <div class="a">
            <div class="a1"><p style="mix-blend-mode: color-burn">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a2"><p style="mix-blend-mode: color-burn">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a3"><p style="mix-blend-mode: color-burn">Hello</p></div>
            <p class="a4">color-burn</p>
        </div>
        <div class="a">
            <div class="a1"><p style="mix-blend-mode: hard-light">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a2"><p style="mix-blend-mode: hard-light">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a3"><p style="mix-blend-mode: hard-light">Hello</p></div>
            <p class="a4">hard-light</p>
        </div>
        <div class="a">
            <div class="a1"><p style="mix-blend-mode: soft-light">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a2"><p style="mix-blend-mode: soft-light">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a3"><p style="mix-blend-mode: soft-light">Hello</p></div>
            <p class="a4">soft-light</p>
        </div>
        <div class="a">
            <div class="a1"><p style="mix-blend-mode: difference">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a2"><p style="mix-blend-mode: difference">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a3"><p style="mix-blend-mode: difference">Hello</p></div>
            <p class="a4">difference</p>
        </div>
        <div class="a">
            <div class="a1"><p style="mix-blend-mode: plus-darker">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a2"><p style="mix-blend-mode: plus-darker">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a3"><p style="mix-blend-mode: plus-darker">Hello</p></div>
            <p class="a4">plus-darker</p>
        </div>
        <div class="a">
            <div class="a1"><p style="mix-blend-mode: plus-lighter">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a2"><p style="mix-blend-mode: plus-lighter">Hello</p></div>
            <div class="a3"><p style="mix-blend-mode: plus-lighter">Hello</p></div>
        <p class="a4">plus-lighter</p>

        <button onclick="changeColor()">Change all p elements color</button>
        <script>
            function changeColor() {
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "color";
                input.value = "#000000";
                input.addEventListener("input", function() {
                    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
                    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                        elements[i].style.color = input.value;
                    }
                });
                input.click();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}
.a {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50px 50px 50px 150px;
    grid-template-rows: 50px;
}

.a p {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-self: center;
    margin: 0;
}

.a1 {
    background-color: white;
    mix-blend-mode: color-dodge;
}

.a2 {
    background-color: #7f7f7f;
}

.a3 {
    background-color: black;
}

.a4 {
    color: black !important;
}

Tried all blend modes

I’m not clear how you are defining contrast - could you explain more?

Adding a new element and event listener on every button element click is not  a great idea here but you never actually put the new element IN the DOM.
